# jquery form extension ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#html

I have multiple forms on a single page. They all use the same class "myForm". 
Using the above extension I can get them to successfully process and POST to `ajax-process.php`.

```
<script> 
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('.myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

I'm having an issue however with the response. I need to get the comment that the user submitted to be displayed in the respective div that it was submitted from. I can either set this as a hidden field in the form, or as text in the `ajax-process.php` file.

I can't work out how to get the response from `ajax-process.php` into something I can work with in the script, if I run the following it appends to all the forms (obviously).

The only way I can think to do it is to repeat the script using individual DIV ID's instead of a single class. However there must be a way of updating the div that the `ajax-process.php` returns.

```
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // bind form using ajaxForm 
    $('.myForm').ajaxForm({ 
        // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 
        target: '.myDiv', 

        // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
        // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content 
        success: function() { 
            $('.myDiv').fadeIn('slow'); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Documentation:

success

Callback function to be invoked after the form has been submitted. If a 'success' callback function is provided it is invoked after the response has been returned from the server. It is passed the following arguments:

1. responseText or responseXML value (depending on the value of the dataType option).
2. statusText
3. xhr (or the jQuery-wrapped form element if using jQuery < 1.4)
4. jQuery-wrapped form element (or undefined if using jQuery < 1.4)

---

That means that your options can look like this:

```
$('.myForm').ajaxForm({
    // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
    // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content 
    success: function(response, undefined, undefined, form) {
        //find .myDiv class in the current form
        form.find('.myDiv').html(response).fadeIn('slow');
    }
});​
```

​
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/XvXEN/)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is I have 5 forms with 5 different divs! myDiv1, myDiv2 etc. I need to update the right one!

Comment: I'm sure it would, but it will always update the same div regardless of which form submitted the data right? It would update myDiv instead of myDiv2 if form2 submitted the AJAX request?

Comment: Thanks. So how would I implement this? Does the ajax-process.php need to return the div name? (bit of a jQuery novice!)

Comment: ajax-process.php should return what it should be placed to the output div, my fiddle search through response just to not to kill whole dom as jsfiddle / not made to answer on custom POST

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21194/discussion-between-eicto-and-craig-wilson)

Comment: Hi - did you get my chat message?!

Comment: seems yes, but chat deleted

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind form using ajaxForm
    $('.myDiv').each(function() {
        var self = this;
        $(this).find("form").ajaxForm({
            // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response
            target: this,

            // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response
            // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content
            success: function() {
                $(self).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[Working sample (Press "run" before pressing buttons)](http://jsfiddle.net/johnsmith123/VFVpU/)

Comment: 4th parameter of `success` calback is current form

Comment: (or undefined if using jQuery < 1.4)

Comment: show me one who use qQuery 1.4 for new code... and why `self` not `$(this)` ?

Comment: because this in context of anonymous function would be different

Comment: why `var self=this` and not `var self=$(this)` ?

Comment: target: Identifies the element(s) in the page to be updated with the server response. This value may be specified as a jQuery selection string, a **jQuery object**, or a **DOM element**. why `'#' + $(this).attr("id")` here ?

Comment: why not var self=$(this) - it would have been var $self = $(this)